# How to disable profile2 types?

Tags: users

I have some types provided by the [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module that I want to disable, but not delete.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way would be to disable permissions for viewing or editing the profiles for specific user roles. Those roles won't be able to see them.

There are a few "things" that can be disabled (without deleting them) in Drupal - Views and Panels are some of them.

Answer (score 0):

May it can help you

[Profile2 Privacy](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_privacy)

> This module extends [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) by allowing administrators to create
>   privacy levels as predefined groups or sets of profile fields on a per
>   role basis. Users can then select from among the privacy levels to
>   apply access control to their profile.